# JsonConvert failing to deserialize integer

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, json-deserialization, flask-restful

I am trying to use python code in Xamarin forms (cross platform) so I tried flask-restful (python API) to build web server and call it from the Xamarin app ,I do not use database I just want to return an integer now, but it's failing at `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <int>(jasonstring);`
and this is how I consume rest API in xamarin

```cs
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:50024/");
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var jasonstring= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             var type = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <int>(jasonstring);


            await DisplayAlert("Result", type.ToString(), "OK");
        }
```

and this the content of contentstring :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xlmns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="info">
    <h2> 1 <br/></h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and what I want to display just this integer (1).

Comment: You should review your API. When you send request, it should be return part of resources. Your API response seems not usable.

Comment: So you are trying to deserialize XML as JSON, somehow pretending the whole thing is an integer? And then you really wonder what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: it's first rest api for me I don't know how to return integer

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft Json .Net is for deserializing an object represented in Json.  You are trying to deserialize Html (xml) with a json deserializer which wont work.  I would recommend using something like the Html Agility Pack to get the number from the h2 block

http://html-agility-pack.net/